# FlowRouter is not defined in individual templates

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

Using Meteor, I started with a default Meteor project with...

```
meteor create --full
```

I added a route, in router.js, like so:

```
FlowRouter.route('/group/:_id', {
  name: 'App.groups.show',
  action() {
    if (!logged_in()) {
      FlowRouter.go("App.home");
    }
    else {
      this.render('App_body', 'Group');
    }
  },
});
```

router.js is here:

```
/imports/startup/client/router.js
```

The Group template is this:

```
<template name="Group">
  
  {{> user_group}}

</template>
```

And for user_group, I have this:

```
Template.user_group.onCreated(function user_groupOnCreated() {
  console.log("id", FlowRouter.getParam('_id'));
});
```

This results in:

```
ReferenceError: FlowRouter is not defined
    at Blaze.TemplateInstance.user_groupOnCreated (user-group.js:46)
    at template.js:119
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (template.js:490)
    at fireCallbacks (template.js:115)
    at Blaze.View.<anonymous> (template.js:195)
    at fireCallbacks (view.js:276)
    at Object.Tracker.nonreactive (tracker.js:603)
    at view.js:273
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (view.js:533)
    at Object.Blaze._fireCallbacks (view.js:272)
```

I also do not have access to `FlowRouter.go` in my templates.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you import FlowRouter in the Template file?

Comment: I do not, explicitly. It was my understanding that, by putting router.js in startup, it is loaded.

Comment: I updated my question with info on router.js.

Comment: That still does not answer, whether you do `import { FlowRouter } from ...` in your Template file

Comment: Ah. I see. I was under the impression that the inclusion of FlowRouter at the start was the equivalent of importing it throughout the project.

Comment: To be clearer, I import FlowRouter in router.js.

Comment: You're right. I had to include FlowRouter in user_group.js. :/ If you make an answer of this, I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import `FlowRouter` in every js that actively uses it (in your example the Template):

```js
import { FlowRouter } from 'meteor/kadira:flow-router'

Template.user_group.onCreated(function user_groupOnCreated() {
  console.log("id", FlowRouter.getParam('_id'))
})
```